# Gcloud command get full resource name without manual concatenation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Normally I would expect to get a fully qualified resource name by just typing for example

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions list --format(value.fullName)
```

Instead I just found a manual lookup table with some examples, which does not seem to be convenient to work with in the cloud shell.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/full-resource-names

Is something like this currently possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can get very similar values like this

Use the `--uri` option

```
> gcloud pubsub subscriptions list --uri

https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/priv-func
https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/push-secure
https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/gcf-function-1-us-central1-test-topic
https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/pusub-logger
https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/pubsub-logger-filtered1
https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/test-iap
```

Or get the resource name

```
> gcloud pubsub subscriptions list --format="value(name)"

projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/priv-func
projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/push-secure
projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/gcf-function-1-us-central1-test-topic
projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/pusub-logger
projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/pubsub-logger-filtered1
projects/my-project-id/subscriptions/test-iap
```